# Javascript ForEach Function does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, internet-explorer-8, foreach

how could I write the following Code that it is supported in all browsers?
Because it seems that the forEach-Function is not supported in IE8...

```
    digits.forEach( function( value, index ) {
    // create a span with initial conditions
    var span = $( '<span>', {
        'class': 'digit0',
        'data': {
            'current': 0,
            'goal' : value
        }
    } );
    // append span to the div#number
    span.appendTo( $( 'div#number' ) );
    // call countUp after interval multiplied by the index of this span
    setTimeout( function() { countUp.call( span ); }, index * interval );
} );
```

**See the full Code here**: http://jsfiddle.net/bBadM/ (it´s not working with all browsers)
Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: Internet Explorer doesn't support "for each" loops. You will need to change the code to use regular for loops:

Comment: You can use pure javascript for loop for this, and jQuery are ending support of old browsers like IE8

Comment: Since you already use jQuery, use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Answer (score 10):

The [MDN documentation for `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) includes two implementations of the method for use in browsers that implement earlier versions of JS.

I'll reproduce the quick one (see the link for the complete one) here:

```
if ( !Array.prototype.forEach ) {
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
      fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Especially Internet Explorer 11!  Come on, Microsoft!