# IE Mobile-Style Menu Issue JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, mobile

I have the following JQuery:

```
function Dropdown(opts) {
    this.opts = opts;
    this.trigger = $(opts.trigger);
    this.menu = $(opts.menu);

    this.hide = this.hide.bind(this);
    this.hideCallbacks = [];
    this.onHide = this.hideCallbacks.push.bind(this.hideCallbacks);
}

Dropdown.prototype.alignMenu = function () {
    if (!this.opts.position) return;

    var pos = this.trigger.position();

    var x = pos.left;
    var y = pos.top;

    var current = this.opts.position === 'activeItem' && this.menu.find('.active');
    if (!current.length) current = this.menu.children(':first');
    y -= current.position().top + (current.outerHeight(true) - this.trigger.outerHeight(true)) / 2;

    this.menu.css({ top: y, left: x });
};

Dropdown.prototype.show = function () {
    this.menu.show();
    this.alignMenu();
    this.menu.find('.active').focus();

    var doc = $(document);

    // If a dropdown trigger is only visible on :hover, hide the menu when the trigger vanishes.
    this.activeBind(doc, 'mouseout', function (e) {
        if (!$.contains(e.target, this.trigger[0])
            && e.target !== this.menu[0] && !$.contains(this.menu[0], e.target))    // Only catch mouseouts on parents of the trigger
            return;
        if (this.trigger.css('visibility') === 'hidden' || this.trigger.is(':hidden'))
            this.hide();
    }.bind(this));

        this.activeBind(this.menu.children(), 'click', this.hide);

    //Prevent the handler that opened the menu in the first place from opening it again.
    // Wait until this event finishes, in case we were shown before bubbling up to here.
    setTimeout(function () {
        this.activeBind(this.trigger, 'click', function (e) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            this.hide();
            return false;
        }.bind(this));

        // Hide on outer mouse click
        this.activeBind(doc, 'click', function (e) {
            if (e.target === this.menu[0] || $.contains(this.menu[0], e.target))
                return; // Ignore clicks inside the menu
            this.hide();
            return false;
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this), 1);

    // Make keyboard start from hovered item
    this.activeBind(this.menu.children(), 'mouseenter', function (e) {
        e.target.focus();
    }.bind(this));
    // Allow navigation via keyboard
    this.activeBind(doc, 'keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) this.hide();
        if (!/(38|40)/.test(e.keyCode)) return;

        var items = this.menu.children();

        if (!items.length) return;

        var index = items.index(document.activeElement || items.filter('.active'));

        if (e.keyCode === 38 && index > 0) index--;                               // up
        if (e.keyCode === 40 && index < items.length - 1) index++;                // down
        if (index < 0) index = 0;

        items.eq(index).focus();

        return false;
    }.bind(this));
};

Dropdown.prototype.hide = function () {
    this.menu.hide();
    this.hideCallbacks.forEach(Function.call.bind(Function.call));
};

Dropdown.prototype.activeBind = function (elem, eventName, handler) {
    elem.bind(eventName, handler);
    this.hideCallbacks.push(function () { elem.unbind(eventName, handler); });
};

$(document).on('click', '.UserTrigger', function () {
    var menu = $('#userMenu'), trigger = $(this);

    var header = $(this).closest('header');
    header.addClass("MenuOpen");

    var dropdown = new Dropdown({ trigger: trigger, menu: menu });
    dropdown.onHide(function () { header.removeClass("MenuOpen"); });
    setScrollDisabled(true, true);
    dropdown.onHide(function () { setScrollDisabled(false, true); });

    dropdown.show();

    // automatically stops propagation
    return false;
});

function setScrollDisabled(value, mobileOnly) {
    var className = mobileOnly ? "OverlaidBase-Mobile" : "OverlaidBase";
    if (value) {
        $('.BaseContent').css('top', -$(window).scrollTop()).addClass(className);
        $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop());
    } else {
        var y = parseInt($('.BaseContent').css('top'), 10);
        $('.BaseContent').removeClass(className);
        setTimeout(function () { $(window).scrollTop(-y); }, 0);
    }
}
```

However in IE i get the following js error:

```
Webpage error details
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 387
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/new-brand/business-sites/dorset-dub-fest/js/dorset-core.js
```

Line 387 is this:
`this.hideCallbacks.forEach(Function.call.bind(Function.call));`

What is the issue, and how can I fix it? Any Ideas SO?

Comment: Not sure if IE supports ```forEach``` more info here with appropriate fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827406/javascript-foreach-function-does-not-work-in-ie#answer-14827443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @varinder, this is the solution:

By adding this at the top of the script:

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
{
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisArg */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
        fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t);
    }
  };
}
```

It resolved the issue, for anyone wanting to know the issue is caused because Internet Explorer doesn't support "for each" loops.

This snippet is from the MDN Docs and is from ECMA-262. The Snippet is the equivalent to the ECMA-262 foreach function.

See [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for more info.